# edit a raster using batch file in command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a batch file for windows command line to convert values of 0 to 1. I can change the numbers with ease but am struggling with the batch file process. I want the batch file to search through 3 degrees of folders to find images to process. So far I have...
UPDATE: The problem appears to have been solved. But for reference the batch file didn't seem to be working, no error messages, just no output.

```
for %%y in (D:\Data\imageA\20*) do (
    cd %%y
    for %%m in (\%%y\*) do (
        cd %%m
        for %%d in (\%%m\*) do (
            cd %%d
            for %%f in (imageA_*_raster) do replacetool %%f %%f_new 0 1
            cd ..
        ) 
        cd ..
    )
    cd ..
)
```

Comment: so what problem do you experience? Is the problem with the batch file not working or the replacetool not working? are you getting an error?

Comment: Be sure to comment out or remove any and all @ECHO OFF statements. Does the output suggest that anything is incorrect? Edit the question to copy and paste in any error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To enumerate directories rather than files, you need to use `for /D`.
2. Put quotation marks around all paths, like `"D:\Data\imageA\20*"`, for example. Use the `~` modifier of `for` variable references to avoid double-quotation.
3. Remove the `cd` commands, use absolute paths instead, applying the `~F` modifier, like `for /D %%m in ("%%~Fy\*") do ( ... )`.
4. If you insist of using relative paths (in case the `replacetool` needs such), use `pushd "%%~y"` instead of `cd %%y` and `popd` instead of `cd ..`, and change `(\%%y\*)` to `("*")`.

Here is the fixed code, using absolute paths:

```cmd
for /D %%y in ("D:\Data\imageA\20*") do (
    for /D %%m in ("%%~Fy\*") do (
        for /D %%d in ("%%~Fm\*") do (
            for %%f in ("%%~Fd\imageA_*_raster") do replacetool "%%~Ff" "%%~Ff_new" 0 1
        )
    )
)
```

Here is the code, using relative paths:

```cmd
for /D %%y in ("D:\Data\imageA\20*") do (
    pushd "%%~y"
    for /D %%m in ("*") do (
        pushd "%%~m"
        for /D %%d in ("*") do (
            pushd "%%~d"
            for %%f in ("imageA_*_raster") do replacetool "%%~f" "%%~f_new" 0 1
            popd
        )
        popd
    )
    popd
)
```